# Docker Nginx with nuxt.js and hot reload setup

Tags: node.js, docker, docker-compose, nuxt.js

### Problem

Currently I can only create simple Dockerfiles but I have no experience with `docker-compose`. I have taken over a project where a static page was
built with `Nuxt.js`. I want to build a development environment where I can work
with `hot reload` or just a copy which immediately transfers the change to the nginx service.

Currently, only when I building a container, the dist folder is copied into the `nginx/html` folder. So I can then call the page.

### Question:

What can I do so that the `nginx/html` folder is overwritten (hot reload)
when saving the Vue file?

I found an interesting approach on SO (option 4). https://stackoverflow.com/a/64010631/8466673
But I don't know how to configure a docker-compose from my one docker file.

**My dockerfile**

```
# build project
FROM node:14 AS build
WORKDIR /app
COPY package.json ./
RUN npm install
COPY . .
RUN npm run build

# create nginx server
FROM nginx:1.19.0-alpine AS prod-stage
COPY --from=build /app/dist /usr/share/nginx/html
EXPOSE 80
CMD [ "nginx", "-g", "daemon off;" ]
```

Comment: Can you use plain Node, without Docker, for this sort of day-to-day development work?  The Dockerfile you show is a very normal production-oriented Dockerfile, building a compact image with just Nginx and the built application, but it can't really be used for live reloading.

Comment: @DavidMaze You mean install node on the local machine? That would definitely make it easy and I wouldn't even need a docker. However, I wanted to avoid installing node, apache, nginx etc on the local machine. Since eventually another project will need a different node version. Then I would have to upgrade or downgrade. Do you think my fear is justified or does it matter?

Comment: Particularly for front-end projects, I haven't found the Node version matters at all.  If it does, version managers like `nvm` support running different versions of Node, directly on the host, without Docker's filesystem isolation and the complications that brings.

Comment: @DavidMaze Thank you very much for your good comments!